# Mapping Model Entity Framework 4 Code First

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

Could anyone help me to define the relationship mapping using EF 4.3. I am a little bit lost when trying to model them in code first

The logic is here.

1. A City has 1 or more Locations (e.g. District 1, CBD, South, North)
2. A Location has 0 or more Venues
3. A Venue may belongs to 1 Location (e.g. New York CBD or South New York) or belong to 1 City if city is small and without any location  (e.g. Hawaii) and 1 Owner
4. Display No. of venues in City. If a City has locations then display no. of all venues in all locations belongs to City. Otherwise display no.of venues belongs to that City only.

Here is my model

```
public class City
{
    private ICollection<Location> _locations;
    private ICollection<Venue> _venues;

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations
    {
        get { return _locations ?? (_locations = new List<Location>()); }
        protected set { _locations = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Venue> Venues
    {
        get { return _venues ?? (_venues = new List<Venue>()); }
        protected set { _venues = value; }
    }
}

public class Location 
{
    private ICollection<Venue> _venues;

    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int CityID{get;set;}
    public virtual City City {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Venue> Venues
    {
        get { return _venues ?? (_venues = new List<Venue>()); }
        protected set { _venues = value; }
    }
}

public class Owner
{
    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int VenueID {get;set;}
    public virtual Venue Venue {get;set;}
}

public class Venue
{
    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int LocationID {get;set;}
    public virtual Location VenueLocation {get;set;}

    public virtual int VenueCityID{get;set;}
    public virtual City VenueCity {get;set;}

    public virtual int VenueOwnerID{get;set;}
    public virtual Owner VenueOwner {get;set;}
}
```

I tried to map those model but very confusing when trying to map the Location , City and Venue

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<City> City{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Locations> Locations{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Owner> Owners{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Venue> Venues{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasRequired(loc => loc.City)
                .WithMany(c => c.Locations)
                .HasForeignKey(loc => loc.CityID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Venue>()
           .HasRequired(v => v.VenueOwner)
           .WithRequiredPrincipal();

        //confusing here when trying to map Location & City for this venue
        modelBuilder.Entity<Venue>()
           .HasRequired(v => v.Location)
           .WithRequiredPrincipal();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Venue>()
           .HasRequired(v => v.City)
           .WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it simpler if you just stick with your statements in points 1 and 2.  Then a small city would have a locations collection, but with only one entry.

Also your locations would have a collectino of venues, and venues would belong only to owners and locations.

Then you'd have:

```
public class City
{
    private ICollection<Location> _locations;

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations
    {
        get { return _locations ?? (_locations = new List<Location>()); }
        protected set { _locations = value; }
    }
}

public class Location 
{
    private ICollection<Venue> _venues;

    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual City City {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Venue> Venues
    {
        get { return _venues ?? (_venues = new List<Venue>()); }
        protected set { _venues = value; }
    }
}

public class Owner
{
    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int VenueID {get;set;}
    public virtual Venue Venue {get;set;}
}

public class Venue
{
    public virtual int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Location VenueLocation {get;set;}

    public virtual Owner VenueOwner {get;set;}
}
```

A query for all venues in a city would then look like:

```
city.Locations.SelectMany(l => l.Venues);
```

Comment: I know it simpler if City only contains collection of Locations, however if I would like to get all venues of small city e.g. Hawaii, how can I do the query when small city didn't have any location at all

Comment: Make it so a city has to have at least one location.  A small city would have a single location which contains all the venues in that city.  This way you can process large and small cityies with the same code.

Comment: How do you map the model so the city have at least one location? Actually I am still not convince this approach i.e. I have to define the city then location of the city e.g. Albury town in NSW and Albury location?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I know it looks a bit redundant, but it makes the rest of your code much simpler.  The mapping just has to set up the relationship between the tables so that a city has many locations.  The number of locations a city actually has is set up in your code.